# Ionic 2/3 - Prevent splashscreen on resume

Tags: android, ionic2, ionic3

I have an Ionic 2 app with a custom splash screen.

My problem is that the app is showing the splash screen every time, not only on opening. If it goes to background and then I come back, even for a short period of time, it shows the splash screen again (which I think is undesirable). Is there any way to prevent this behaviour?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look in your config.js file and search for the preference `SplashShowOnlyFirstTime`.

If you have this tag set it to `true`, by default it is true, so if you don't have this tag in your code then it must be something else.

This is the full tag:

```
<preference name="SplashShowOnlyFirstTime" value="true" />
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: It was set to false, indeed. Works like a charm... Thank you so much! (gonna accept your answer soon)

Comment: @RonanLopes i think that in the newer versions of Ionic it's by default beein seted to `false` and like you i think it's bad, since the app wasn't killed there's no reason to show the splash again. But i'm glad it helped.